# Excel VBA code to get the original width of a column before it was hidden

Tags: excel, vba

I set a width of completely empty column 'E' to 29 points and hide the column.

I then 'Go To' cell E1 (via Control+G command) and look for 'Format -> Column Width' and it correctly shows the width as zero because column 'E' is hidden.

If I then unhide column E, the width of the column is restored back to the original 29. Excel remembers this somehow.

I would like to see the VBA code to retrieve the original width of a column before it was hidden.

Comment: turn off screenupdating, unhide, get the width, hide it again, turn updating back on

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you really can't. However, you **can** quickly unhide it, get the width, and rehide the column without the user even noticing.

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print Range("A:A").ColumnWidth    '0

    'unhide the column
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Debug.Print Range("A:A").ColumnWidth    '30

    'rehide the column
    Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Range("A:A").ColumnWidth    '0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but how does the excel application do it? It must be storing the original width of a column somewhere inside the file

Comment: You’re right I’m sure it is but that’s unfortunately beyond me!